# what command is it used when click restart from start menu in win7

Tags: windows

i'm making a windows pe disk, I tried to reboot with Restart button from start menu, somehow, it does not work( no reaction at all)

any idea what is the command being used when clicking on restart button? 
is it 
`"shutdown -r -t 0"` ? how can i make change to that command then?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you can create a bat file with the command.  Open up the Editor and put the following command in there:

shutdown - r -t 0

Now click save and Name it like reboot.bat the bat After the file is important

Sorry that i can only tell you an alternative way : P

Comment: i'd prefer dont use bat/cmd file

Comment: You can search in your BIOS the Option named "restore Power after Power loss"  or something like that and turn it on. Then your PC will reboot when you plug out the ac

Comment: please note: im using WINPE, making changes on every BIOS is not feasible. so what i need to find out is what command running behind restart button

Comment: once find out what command is run behind scene, I'd look for a way to change it so that it points to specific exe file I want to use to restart

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way would be to shutdown using GUI.  This procedure is for the computers located in remote location, but works even in local computer.

Open CMD - shutdown /I - Press enter - Add name of your local host name.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: i want to just use windows original restart power button

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that you can't do that. You need to troubleshoot what is going wrong with restarting. The graphical user interface and command line interface are two different "shells" that access an underlying program that is the operating system. It's not like the GUI just activates commands. So, you're talking about hacking the operating system, which would mean knowing which bytes to replace in an executable or .dll file or something. And which "specific exe file" would you want to change a command to anyway? This question is questionable.